# Iframe still active in case of downtime?

Tags: iframe

I have 2 sites domain1.com and domain2.com hosted on different server.

On domain1.com I have a page with inside a Iframe who point to domain2.com. Users of domain1.com are supposed to stay many hours on the "Iframe" page for make some task trough the content displayed by domain2.com.

Now I wondering in case domain1.com go down for some minutes or more (because server/network problem or maintenance) if users still be able to work inside Iframe or not. I don't know how to simulate this case reason why I ask you.

I suppose if domain1.com is down, when user will click on any link present in Iframe/domain2.com will result to get the content of iframe unavailable too...or maybe not ?

thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no background task(like AJAX) in domain1 is necessary and there is no interaction(like HTTP requests) between domain1 and domain2 while users are working in domain2 IFrame, they will be able to work on it even if domain1 is down, since IFrame is independent from the main Webpage.